# Python merging data frames and renaming column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python, I have a df that looks like this

```
Name    ID
Anna    1
Sarah   2
Max     3
```

And a df that looks like this

```
Name    ID
Dan     1
Hallie  2
Cam     3
```

How can I merge the df’s so that the ID column looks like this

```
Name    ID
Anna    1
Sarah   2
Max     3
Dan     4
Hallie  5
Cam     6
```

This is just a minimal reproducible example. My actual data set has 1000’s of values. I’m basically merging data frames and want the ID’s in numerical order (continuation of previous data frame) instead of repeating from one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2.assign(ID=df2['ID'] + df1['ID'].max())], ignore_index=True)
print(out)

# Output
     Name  ID
0    Anna   1
1   Sarah   2
2     Max   3
3     Dan   4
4  Hallie   5
5     Cam   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the two DataFrames, `reset_index` and use the new index to assign "ID"s

```
df_new = pd.concat((df1, df2)).reset_index(drop=True)
df_new['ID'] = df_new.index + 1
```

Output:

```
     Name  ID
0    Anna   1
1   Sarah   2
2     Max   3
3     Dan   4
4  Hallie   5
5     Cam   6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat dataframes with `ignore_index=True` and then set ID column:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
df['ID'] = df.index + 1
```